# Multitool attachment sets for quick release reciprocating saws

Tags: powertools

I just purchased this cordless reciprocating saw:  [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B089QGR718/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B089QGR718)

[image]

It has a quick-release blade holder

[image]

for quick-release blades like this

[image]

Are there any attachment sets available for this type of tool - along the lines of what we see here for the big names brands?

[https://www.amazon.com/Oscillating-Multitool-Universal-Accessories-Milwaukee/dp/B087DYRP56/ref=sr_1_47?dchild=1&keywords=reciprocating+saw+accessory+attachments&qid=1618685207&s=hi&sr=1-47](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B087DYRP56)

[image]

I am trying to understand what are the different types of chucks/adapters used for reciprocating saws - and if that difference is why there are so few attachments available. I don't need help on "shopping" but on tool/[brand?] categories. Given such a sizeable set of name branders use one approach - is there a name for that 3/4 circle chuck/adapter?

Comment: Multitool has different chuck.

Comment: OK so then this is a saw and essentially that's that I take it

Comment: Vote to close. This is a shopping question.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate   I am trying to understand what are the different types of chucks/adapters used for reciprocating saws - and if that difference is why there are so few attachments available.   The question was updated.

Comment: Multitools and reciprocating saws are two different tools.  Can get sets for reciprocating saws or sets for multitools.  One is a forward/back motion the other is more side to side motion(I think).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica OK thanks for that clarification - please make that an answer

Comment: You can get a variety of interesting diamond or carbide edge reciprocating saw blades if you look hard enough.  Can do some cuts in tile and cinderblock that are hard with a grinder or rotary saw.

Comment: Vote to close retracted. I misunderstood the intent of the original version of the question. Thanks to the OP for clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### They are completely different types of tool.

The item you bought is a **reciprocating saw** commonly known as a Sawzall.  It vibrates **in/out** with great force.  It is designed to use saw blades which have the cutting teeth **on the side** of the blade.  It uses a semi-standard blade shape which looks like an "L" with a dot.

There's a totally different type of tool called an **oscillating saw**.  This head vibrates in 4 directions (sort of like "Wax on/wax off" if you are waxing a car).  When it has saw blades, the cutting teeth are **on the end** of the blade. However it supports a huge variety of other tool heads which can benefit form the *oscillating* motion. It has a quick-disconnect type that looks like a big asterisk with a side missing, to allow you to position the heads at a variety of angles.

Reciprocating saws are beasts that can cut through 1/2" thick steel with the right blade.  Oscillating saws are much more dainty, intended for finer work, and don't have nearly the same cutting force.  You don't worry about cutting your arm off with an oscillating saw.

The second set of tool heads you linked are for **oscillating saws**.  They won't work on a **reciprocating saw** any more than a band-saw blade would work on a chain-saw.

---

Note that everything you linked is cheap Chinese crud from third-party "eBay tier" sellers on Amazon's little flea market they call "Amazon Marketplace". Expect these tools to very quickly fail, and the tools may be dangerous, since they bypass all consumer-safety laws by selling direct through Amazon.  Unfortunately, Amazon mixes these junk products in with their regular search results with no ability to filter, and you often have to muck through pages of these to find a product actually worth buying.

Since Home Depot and Lowes also have online catalogs, and their stuff does not bypass the safety laws,  and they have "curbside" so I can get it same day, I buy there instead.

Comment: Thx for the clarification on the oscillating tools vs the sawzall . As far as the cheap tools that's fine since there is a variety of jobs needed presently but then I won't have much more to do probably for several years. I also face a higher likelihood of the tools being stolen.

Answer (score 2):

The only special attachment for a reciprocating saw I have seen is scraper blades, e.g.,  https://www.lowes.com/pd/Spyder-3-Pack-Reciprocating-Saw-Scraper-Attachments/1000060921?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-tol-_-google-_-lia-_-215-_-pta-drillinganddriving-_-1000060921-_-0&placeholder=null&ds_rl=1286981&gclid=CjwKCAjwjuqDBhAGEiwAdX2cj1keJfso5apOXYedben7-1xW0Ktcokagp6yf3biVyQPiXbNQ1ATbWhoCpYoQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds.

Comment: I did see the Spyder's on amazon: maybe that's about all  there is .  What is that  3/4 circle attachment /bit holder used by Fei, B&D, Bosch, Milwaukee etc called?

Comment: It is pretty clear those blades for reciprocating saw.